# Docker-compose Daemon mode logs

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running several containers in daemon mode: `docker-compose up -d`.

One of them recently crashed.

I'd like to investigate what happened. Where can I find the app logs?

Here's the `docker-compose.yml` (nothing special regarding logging):

```
mongodb:
  image: mongo
  command: "--smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null"
web:
  build: .
  command: npm start
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  ports:
    - "3001:3000"
  links:
    - mongodb
  environment:
    PORT: 3000
    NODE_ENV: 'production'
seed:
 build: ./seed
 links:
   - mongodb
```

Comment: Does `docker-compose logs` not give you what you need?

Comment: It might. :) I actually did not think of this and was searching for a log file instead.

Comment: But what if I actually want to store this into files?

Comment: You can define the directory where the logs go as a `volume`. Then inspect those files using another lightweight container using `--volumes-from`. The dirtier way of course is to go and take a look in the file system of the container on the host (`/var/lib/docker/containers/`), but it's possible of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get logs via [`docker-compose logs`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/logs/) or you could [exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) to attach (docker >= 1.3) to the running instance via

```
$ docker exec -i -t 6655b41beef /bin/bash #by ID
or
$ docker exec -i -t my_www /bin/bash #by Name
```